# Composite Primary keys and auto increment?

Tags: mysql, database-design, replication, innodb, trigger

i'm developing SaaS app with multi-tenancy, and i've decide to use single DB (MySQL Innodb for now) for client's data. I chose to use composite primary keys like  **PK(client_id, id)**. I have 2 ways here,

**1: increment "id" by myself (by trigger or from code)**

or

**2: Make "id" as auto-increment by mysql.**

In first case i will have unique **id's** for each client, so each client will have id 1, 2, 3 etc..
In second case id's will grow for all clients.
What is the best practice here? My priorities are: performace, security & scaling. Thanks!
[Same question at stackoverflow with more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305739/composite-primary-keys-and-auto-increment-what-is-a-good-practices/37306231)

Comment: Please link to the outer place where you asked the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The second option should be the fastest. It was made for this. Also it should have no bugs since it is used a lot and already for a long time. If you go for this then you do not even need to use a composite primary key.

In my opinion the only reason to use the first option is if you need a numbering starting from 1 per client.